# Cryptography notation

Tags: cryptography

If I wrote RC5-32/12/16, it would mean 32-bit words (which is 64-bit data blocks). What is "words".

I know the 12 is rounds and 16 is key size (16 bytes, so 128 bit).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word size can be 16, 32, or 64 bits, and it determines the block size.  "The algorithm assumes that the input block is given in two w-bit registers A and B..."  This allows for optimization based on the target architecture.

Reference: [The RC5 Encryption Algorithm (PDF)](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rivest-TheRC5EncryptionAlgorithm)